# Mapping JSON objects together in VueJS

Tags: json, vue.js

I need to display some answers to questions and how many people voted on each answer.

I've got the questions to appear for each group of people as well as the answers to the questions but I can't get the results of the votes to appear under each answer.

I'm getting the results to all three questions under each question. I just can't wrap my head around it as I'm quite new to VueJS.

I understand that having `{{response}}` on it's own is the reason I'm getting all the data but I can't figure out how to only show the relevant result.

Here's my code:

```
              <b-tabs pills card vertical>
                <div v-for="departmentData in departments" :key="departmentData.id" class="department-data">
                <b-tab :title="departmentData.name">
                  <b-card-text>
                    <div>
                       <b-badge variant="dark">{{departmentData.name}}</b-badge>
                    </div>
                    <div v-for="questionData in questions" :key="questionData.id" class="question-data">
                      <div class="questions">
                        <div>
                          <h5>{{questionData.title}}</h5>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="answers">   
                        <div v-for="answer in questionData.answers" :key="answer.id">
                            <div>
                              <h5>{{answer.text}}</h5>
                              <span v-for="response in departmentData.responses" :key="response.id">
                                <p>
                                  {{response}}
                                </p>
                              </span>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                      </div>   
                    </div>
                  </b-card-text>
                  </b-tab>
                </div>
              </b-tabs>
            </b-card>
```

and:

```
 data() {
    return {
      questions: [{
      "title": "question 1 blah blah?",
      "answers": [
        {
          "id": "tv",
          "text": "tv "
        },
        {
          "id": "radio",
          "text": "radio "
        },
        {
          "id": "none",
          "text": "None"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "question 2 blah blah?",
      "answers": [
        {
          "id": "milk",
          "text": "milk "
        },
        {
          "id": "water",
          "text": "water ☕"
        },
        {
          "id": "soda",
          "text": "sod"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "Question 3 blah blah",
      "answers": [
        {
          "id": "book",
          "text": "Book "
        },
        {
          "id": "ebook",
          "text": "eBook "
        }
      ]
    }],

    departments: {
    "ace": {
      "name": "HR",
      "responses": [
        {
          "tv": 50,
          "radio": 37.5,
          "none": 12.5
        },
        {
          "milk": 25,
          "water": 62.5,
          "soda": 12.5
        },
        {
          "book": 87.5,
          "ebook": 12.5
        }
      ]
    },

    "central": {
      "name": "Design",
      "responses": [
        {
          "tv": 66.7,
          "radio": 33.3,
          "none": 0
        },
        {
          "milk": 33.3,
          "water": 66.7,
          "none": 0
        },
        {
          "book": 66.7,
          "ebook": 33.3
        }
      ]
    },
    }
```

Output: 
[image: the result]

JS FIDDLE
https://jsfiddle.net/tbah31vL/

Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a working example? Either in a JSFiddle or in the Vue-Bootstrap playground (since you're using vue-bootstrap)

Comment: @Leite https://jsfiddle.net/tbah31vL/ here you go

Comment: Can you give us an idea how does the output should look like?

Comment: @Macintosh_89 Sure, so for example, Under TV it should just have the number "50" and under Radio it should have 37.5 etc. But I'm getting the answers to all 3 questions under each question's answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only need a couple minor changes actually.

You'll need to keep track of the `index` of the question you're currently looping for, and use that and the `answer.id` to get the correct value.

```
// this
<div v-for="questionData in questions" :key="questionData.id" class="question-data">

// becomes
<div v-for="(questionData, idx) in questions" :key="questionData.id" class="question-data">
```

```
// and this
<p>{{departmentData.responses}}</p>

// to 
<p>{{departmentData.responses[idx][answer.id]}}</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining! I've accepted yours as you helped me to understand it better.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution 
 and here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/nLpxtfm4/

```
    <div id="app">
   <template>
<div class="main">
  <div id="data">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <b-card no-body>
            <b-tabs pills card vertical>
              <div v-for="departmentData in departments" :key="departmentData.id" class="department-data">
                <b-tab :title="departmentData.name">
                  <b-card-text>
                    <div class="deptBadge">
                      <b-badge variant="dark">{{departmentData.name}}</b-badge>
                    </div>
                    <div v-for="questionData in questions" :key="questionData.id" class="question-data">
                      <div class="questions">
                        <div>
                          <h6>{{questionData.title}}</h6>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="answers">
                        <div v-for="answer in questionData.answers" :key="answer.id">
                          <div>
                            <span>{{answer.text}}</span>
                            <p>
                              {{filterResponse(departmentData.name,answer.id)}}
                            </p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </b-card-text>
                </b-tab>
              </div>
            </b-tabs>
          </b-card>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
  return {
    questions: [{
        "title": "Question 1 blah blah blah",
        "answers": [{
            "id": "tv",
            "text": "TV"
          },
          {
            "id": "radio",
            "text": "Radio"
          },
          {
            "id": "none",
            "text": "None"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "title": "Question 2 blah blah blah",
        "answers": [{
            "id": "music",
            "text": "music "
          },
          {
            "id": "art",
            "text": "Art ☕"
          },
          {
            "id": "film",
            "text": "Film"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "title": "Question 3 blah blah blah?",
        "answers": [{
            "id": "book",
            "text": "Book"
          },
          {
            "id": "ebook",
            "text": "eBook"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],

    departments: {
      "group1": {
        "name": "Group 1",
        "responses": [{
            "tv": 50,
            "radio": 37.5,
            "none": 12.5
          },
          {
            "music": 25,
            "art": 62.5,
            "film": 12.5
          },
          {
            "book": 87.5,
            "ebook": 12.5
          }
        ]
      },

      "group2": {
        "name": "Group 2",
        "responses": [{
            "tv": 66.7,
            "radio": 33.3,
            "none": 0
          },
          {
            "music": 33.3,
            "art": 66.7,
            "film": 0
          },
          {
            "book": 66.7,
            "ebook": 33.3
          }
        ]
      },



    }
  }
},

methods: {
  filterResponse: function(group, answer) {
    let answerVal = null
    let deptName = group.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '')
    let responses = this.departments[deptName].responses
    responses.forEach(function(res) {
      if (res.hasOwnProperty(answer)) {
        answerVal = res[ans]
      }
    })

    return answerVal

  }
   }

 })
}
```